# Bash cannot set environment variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this in my crontab:

```
* * * * * cd /etc && . ./cron.sh>>cron.log
```

In my cron.sh (which is executable) I have:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "hello world"
export MyVar="abcd"
```

It runs both with cron and manually, however the environment variable is only set when I run it manually with the command:

```
. ./cron.sh
```

Can anyone please help. I know its something to do with source but I cant figure it out.

This does not work either:

```
* * * * * cd /etc && sh ./cron.sh>>cron.log
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to set a variable for all users

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.` will export variables *in the current shell*, which is the one spawned by the `cron`, not yours.

If you want to add an extra variable to your shells, use the `~/.profile` et al (specifically the `/etc/profile` that is shared by all users).

Comment: Or `/etc/profile`, since that is already shared by all users.

Comment: @chepner that was part of my *et al.* ;) I'll update my answer to enlight that.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to set a variable for all users

You cannot do that via a cron job.

In fact, in general, you can't do it at all.  The environment variables of a shell cannot be set from outside the shell.  The UNIX / Linux operating system architecture doesn't allow it.

You *could* could set an environment variable for all users via `/etc/profile` except ...

1. the `/etc/profile` file is only executed when a user logs in, and
2. the user can override any environment variables set there.